# How to calculate the inverse of a complex matrix?

Tags: matrices, inverse

How can I calculate the inverse of
$$H = \pmatrix{
h_{00} & h_{01} \\
h_{10} & h_{11}},$$
where $h_{00}$, $h_{01}$, $h_{10}$, and $h_{11}$ are complex numbers?

Comment: See [adjugate matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix), i.e. Michael Albanese's answer.

Comment: The same as for real matrix.

Answer (score 11):

It is exactly the same as it is for a real matrix. Let $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{C}$ with $ad - bc \neq 0$ then $$\left[\begin{matrix} a& b\\ c & d\end{matrix}\right]^{-1} = \frac{1}{ad-bc}\left[\begin{matrix}d & -b\\ -c & a\end{matrix}\right].$$

Comment: In fact, it works for any arbitrary field $K$ instead of $\mathbb C$, or unitary commutative rings in which $ad-bc$ is invertible.

Comment: I like writing it this way, so that it's true in any ring whatsoever: $\left[\begin{matrix} a& b\\ c & d\end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix}d & -b\\ -c & a\end{matrix}\right] = (ad-bc)\left[\begin{matrix} 1& 0\\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right]$

Comment: @User-33433: Surely the ring needs to be commutative.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Ah yes, apparently I've picked up the algebraic geometer's bad habit of pronouncing "unitary commutative ring" as "ring".  Though 1 is not really necessary here, noncommutativity does break many familiar properties of matrices.