# Taking inverse of a complex matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, hermitian-matrices

I checked previous posts and it says that I should just follow the same process as in real case. 
However, when I try to find the inverse of a complex matrix with coefficient method, should I take conjugate transpose of the coefficient matrix. 
If it is so, I think they don't give the same result. 
What do I do wrong ?

Comment: Can you post the matrix you are trying to inverse?

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}
2+i &1 \\ 
 1&-2-i 
\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The simplest test:**

Is $\begin{bmatrix} i\end{bmatrix}$ inverted as $\begin{bmatrix} i^{-1}\end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix}i^{*-1}\end{bmatrix}$ ?

Check by performing the product.

---

**Alternatively:**

Consider the system of equations

$$\begin{cases}ax+by=u,\\cx+dy=v\end{cases}$$ where all variables are complex.

Now combining the two equations,

$$d(ax+by)-b(cx+dy)=(ad-bc)y=du-bv$$

so that

$$y=\frac{\begin{vmatrix}u&b\\ v&d\end{vmatrix}}{\begin{vmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{vmatrix}}$$
where the determinants are evaluated as usual.

As you see, there is no "room" for conjugation. Of course this extends to matrix inversion, and to any order.

Comment: so, i should not take conjugate transpose of it ?

Comment: @anonymous: check by performing the product.

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly the same as it is for a real matrix. Of course you need to check that the matrix is non-singular, i.e that the determinant is non-zero.

Comment: $A^{-}=\frac{1}{det(A)}C^{T} or A^{-}=\frac{1}{det(A)}C^{H}$ which one should I use for complex case. and why ?

Comment: You need to take the conjugate transpose of the cofactor (coefficient) matrix, so the first case is fine. What is your matrix? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}
2+i &1 \\ 
 1&-2+i 
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: The determinant is -6, so it's fine and you do the same steps as for a real matrix. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623780/how-to-calculate-the-inverse-of-a-complex-matrix

Comment: if determinant were complex, then should I have taken conjugate transpose of cofactor matrix ?

Comment: Yeah your entries for the first row should be [(2-i)/6  1/6] and in the second row [1/6  -(2+i)/6].

Answer (score 0):

It is the same method: $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix}\right]^{-1}=\frac1{\det A}\left[\begin{smallmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{smallmatrix}\right]$. So, if$$A=\begin{bmatrix}2+i&1\\1&-2-i\end{bmatrix},$$then $\det A=-4-4i$. Therefore,\begin{align}A^{-1}&=\frac1{-4-4i}\begin{bmatrix}-2-i&-1\\-1&2+i\end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}\frac38-\frac i8&\frac18-\frac i8\\
 \frac18-\frac i8&-\frac38+\frac i8\end{bmatrix}.\end{align}

Comment: but you did not take the conjugate transpose of cofactor matrix, shouldn't it be that way ? and $a_{2,1}=1$

Comment: I did not take the conjugate because **to take the conjugate woud be an error**. As you were told, you “should just follow the **same** process as in real case”. And that $-1$ was a typo, but the final answer is correct.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: sorry but you didn't really justify that conjugation would be an error, which is the OP's anxiety. This can be shown by multiplying the two, or by showing why the initial formula is valid for complex as well.